# CSS solution to floating images to right but with no text flowing underneath

Tags: css, layout, css-float

I'd like to know if there is a solution with CSS where I have code like below, and there may or may not be an image floating to the right. I want the text to flow only as far as the left of the image(s), so the text doesn't flow underneath them, almost like it forms its own column.

```
<div class="content">
<h1>Page title</h1>
<img src="path/to/image">
<p>Some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here</p>
<p>More content here</p>
</div>
```

Sometimes there might be more than one image (just after the other), or none at all. Essentially I'm wondering if there is a pure css solution instead of separate columns/divs (and avoiding js). I have a feeling it isn't possible...!

And to complicate things further, it has to be compatible in all the major browsers (including, urgh, ie6).

Answer (score 2):

with css only:

```
img { float: right; width: 100px}
p { margin-right: 100px; } /* margin = image width */
```

play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/mPTRx/

p.s. if you're using more than one image, use `img { float: right; clear: right; }`

Comment: thanks matt! btw, the margin-bottom was my first thought too.

Comment: Won't handle the "no image" scenario (if we don't want 100px empty space).

Comment: @bbazmegakapa: good catch. @WastedSpace: is this an issue? if so, the css-ony solution might get a little more complicated (but still possible, i believe).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks folks!

I have adapted Sebastian's code, but conceded that jQuery has to be involved, as I don't always want there to be a gap on the right.

Here's how I solved it:

HTML (BTW I'm not fully responsible for some of the markup, it is all within a Wordpress site!):

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p><img src="blah" class="alignright"></p>
  <p><img src="blah2" class="alignright"></p>
  <h2>Sub title</h2>
  <p>Some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here, some content here</p>
  <p>More content here</p>
</div>
```

jQuery (part of more complex code):

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); // so no other plugins affect this in Wordpress
$j(document).ready(function() {
if($j('.alignright').length) { //this checks if an image exists
      $j('.content').children().css('margin-right', '250px');
      $j('.alignright').parent().css({'float':'right','width':'230px','margin':'0px 0px 10px 0px','clear':'right'});
    }
}
```

I hope this is useful to somebody! Thanks Sebastian for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.content p { overflow:[hidden|auto]; }
```

should work.

I let you try to understand: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/block_formatting_context ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think  there is a way to do it without including extra divs.

Solution 1:

```
<style>
.content {margin:0 auto 0 auto; width:960px;} 
img {float:right; margin-bottom:100%;}
</style>
<body>

<div class="content">
<h1>Page title</h1>
<div>
<img src="images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" style="width:10%; height:10%;">
<p>Aliquam eget dolor est, fringilla pellentesque magna. Integer suscipit, mauris at adipiscing tincidunt, ipsum libero sollicitudin nisi, tempus adipiscing nulla orci non neque. Aenean arcu leo, mattis sit amet cursus ac, imperdiet eget nulla. Proin porttitor, nulla a rutrum fringilla, ante turpis rhoncus tellus, eu rhoncus turpis massa quis mauris. Maecenas vehicula rutrum dolor sit amet placerat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi eleifend; nisi eget facilisis gravida, magna ipsum faucibus ligula, eget commodo metus nibh vel sapien. Aliquam adipiscing erat non lorem cursus quis interdum nulla elementum. Cras ullamcorper magna non dui rutrum at consectetur libero rhoncus. Nunc nisi nulla, gravida quis convallis eu, molestie sit amet ipsum! Suspendisse potenti. Quisque gravida lobortis massa ac imperdiet. Duis tincidunt lorem pellentesque augue convallis luctus? Quisque purus dolor, aliquam hendrerit ultricies a, semper id tortor. Vestibulum sit amet sem ac magna posuere hendrerit id eu quam. Cras nec urna rutrum odio iaculis iaculis. Suspendisse lobortis pellentesque tristique. Duis felis purus, sodales nec euismod eu, congue et ipsum. Integer tincidunt semper orci, in mollis velit mattis eget. Fusce a tincidunt ante.

Sed quam sem, lobortis vel consectetur id, vestibulum quis lorem? Vivamus ornare sagittis neque sit amet lacinia? Mauris molestie blandit eros, non gravida turpis feugiat nec. Integer pretium ligula sit amet justo iaculis auctor. Praesent lacinia tellus ut libero euismod eu ullamcorper mauris convallis? Ut posuere tempus elit a mollis. Quisque velit neque, vestibulum ac laoreet in, adipiscing at lorem. Sed velit arcu, sagittis et porta non, venenatis ut nisl. Nunc faucibus, orci sed bibendum tempus, purus ligula imperdiet nulla, non lacinia arcu mauris sit amet nunc. Etiam consectetur lectus id nibh facilisis porta. Nunc adipiscing scelerisque egestas. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse euismod molestie nulla, sed suscipit lorem dapibus ac! Curabitur vel mauris justo. Sed urna eros, molestie ut sagittis et, pharetra non arcu! Proin vel nisi ante; at suscipit diam? Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum a lacus libero. Sed nec enim tellus, sit amet pulvinar dolor.

Etiam rhoncus dapibus nibh, vitae adipiscing ante lacinia vel. Vivamus facilisis rutrum sem nec laoreet? Etiam non massa quis tortor euismod scelerisque. Nunc fermentum accumsan rhoncus? Duis ut neque eget nulla fringilla porttitor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur fermentum, ipsum non ullamcorper consectetur, elit diam ullamcorper augue, vitae porta orci lorem nec dolor. Phasellus facilisis feugiat nisl eu consequat. Fusce sit amet dui eget libero congue rutrum. Phasellus sed sem quam, id aliquam leo? Cras massa dolor, laoreet rhoncus condimentum ut, varius in purus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

This drops a massive margin below the image which prevents the text from flowing underneath. You may need to define a height for the div in some browsers.

Solution 2:

```
<style>
.content {margin:0 auto 0 auto; width:960px;} 
div.images {float:right; width:100px;}
div.text {float:left; width:860px;}
</style>
<body>

<div class="content">
<h1>Page title</h1>
<div class="images">
    <img src="images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" style="width:100px;">
</div>
<div class="text">
<p>Aliquam eget dolor est, fringilla pellentesque magna. Integer suscipit, mauris at adipiscing tincidunt, ipsum libero sollicitudin nisi, tempus adipiscing nulla orci non neque. Aenean arcu leo, mattis sit amet cursus ac, imperdiet eget nulla. Proin porttitor, nulla a rutrum fringilla, ante turpis rhoncus tellus, eu rhoncus turpis massa quis mauris. Maecenas vehicula rutrum dolor sit amet placerat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi eleifend; nisi eget facilisis gravida, magna ipsum faucibus ligula, eget commodo metus nibh vel sapien. Aliquam adipiscing erat non lorem cursus quis interdum nulla elementum. Cras ullamcorper magna non dui rutrum at consectetur libero rhoncus. Nunc nisi nulla, gravida quis convallis eu, molestie sit amet ipsum! Suspendisse potenti. Quisque gravida lobortis massa ac imperdiet. Duis tincidunt lorem pellentesque augue convallis luctus? Quisque purus dolor, aliquam hendrerit ultricies a, semper id tortor. Vestibulum sit amet sem ac magna posuere hendrerit id eu quam. Cras nec urna rutrum odio iaculis iaculis. Suspendisse lobortis pellentesque tristique. Duis felis purus, sodales nec euismod eu, congue et ipsum. Integer tincidunt semper orci, in mollis velit mattis eget. Fusce a tincidunt ante.

Sed quam sem, lobortis vel consectetur id, vestibulum quis lorem? Vivamus ornare sagittis neque sit amet lacinia? Mauris molestie blandit eros, non gravida turpis feugiat nec. Integer pretium ligula sit amet justo iaculis auctor. Praesent lacinia tellus ut libero euismod eu ullamcorper mauris convallis? Ut posuere tempus elit a mollis. Quisque velit neque, vestibulum ac laoreet in, adipiscing at lorem. Sed velit arcu, sagittis et porta non, venenatis ut nisl. Nunc faucibus, orci sed bibendum tempus, purus ligula imperdiet nulla, non lacinia arcu mauris sit amet nunc. Etiam consectetur lectus id nibh facilisis porta. Nunc adipiscing scelerisque egestas. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse euismod molestie nulla, sed suscipit lorem dapibus ac! Curabitur vel mauris justo. Sed urna eros, molestie ut sagittis et, pharetra non arcu! Proin vel nisi ante; at suscipit diam? Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum a lacus libero. Sed nec enim tellus, sit amet pulvinar dolor.

Etiam rhoncus dapibus nibh, vitae adipiscing ante lacinia vel. Vivamus facilisis rutrum sem nec laoreet? Etiam non massa quis tortor euismod scelerisque. Nunc fermentum accumsan rhoncus? Duis ut neque eget nulla fringilla porttitor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur fermentum, ipsum non ullamcorper consectetur, elit diam ullamcorper augue, vitae porta orci lorem nec dolor. Phasellus facilisis feugiat nisl eu consequat. Fusce sit amet dui eget libero congue rutrum. Phasellus sed sem quam, id aliquam leo? Cras massa dolor, laoreet rhoncus condimentum ut, varius in purus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

This requires 2 divs, one to hold your images floated right and one to hold your text floated left. Both need a defined width.